# Receiving uevents - are events buffered after uevent_open_socket() is called?

Tags: android, linux, udev

This question is loosely based on the source code for a test which demonstrates receiving uevents, available [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/extras/+/master/tests/uevents/uevents.c).  The relevant code is:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int device_fd;
    char msg[UEVENT_MSG_LEN+2];
    int n;
    int i;
    device_fd = uevent_open_socket(64*1024, true);
    if(device_fd < 0)
        return -1;
    while ((n = uevent_kernel_multicast_recv(device_fd, msg, UEVENT_MSG_LEN)) > 0) {
        msg[n] = '\0';
        msg[n+1] = '\0';
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
            if (msg[i] == '\0')
                msg[i] = ' ';
        printf("%s\n", msg);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I performed two experiments:

1. First, I simply ran this program while plugging and unplugging a device.  I observed connect and disconnect uevent messages being printed, as expected.
2. I added a `sleep(30)` after `uevent_open_socket()`.  I ran the program and again plugged and unplugged a device during the 30-second sleep period.  My **expected behavior** was to see the uevent messages get buffered in the `64*1024`-byte buffer, and later read & printed after the 30-second sleep completed.

   However, the **actual behavior** was that no messages were received after the 30-second sleep.

This raises several questions for me:

1. Are the messages buffered at all?
2. If yes, what is the nature of the buffering strategy, which caused the messages to be dropped entirely and not received?
3. If not, wouldn't messages necessarily be dropped in a hypothetical scenario where messages were generated at a higher frequency than they could be received & handled?